# asp.net redirect fails on undefined id

Tags: asp.net, routes

On the test site, after the user logs in, the redirect fails.

The route is being redirected from

http://localhost:56380/Account/Logon

to

http://localhost:7000/Account/undefined

which gives a 404.

The user is going directly to the login page, so the returnUrl is blank.

DestinationPageUrl is blank.

I find that

RouteData.Route.Url is set to  "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
So I think the id is undefined somehow.

On the production site, I can't trace into the server code, but from F12 it looks like it is going to

https://exampledomain.net/Account/

which then goes to

https://exampledomain.net

and that works.

Searching, I found documentation on how to set up the route "{controller}/{action}/{id}" but nothing about how ID gets populated or how to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an error in the javascript (caused by correcting lint "errors").
It was

```
   var returnUrl = $("#hf-account-returnurl").val();
   if (returnUrl == null)
```

Lint complained about the == and recommended changing it to ===

```
   if (returnUrl === null)
```

$("#hf-account-returnurl").val() returns undefined if it isn't defined. This was the clue that finally led us to look at the JS code.
Undefined == null but it doesn't === null.

Answer (score 0):

Is your id set to UrlParameter.Optional ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for answering.

Comment: I think so. Is that good? RegisterRoutes contains this line:  routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); // Parameter defaults

Comment: Optional doesn't appear to me to be related. It is only used on the way in to set variable values from the URL path. It doesn't seem to me to be used on a redirect. Am I missing something?